# HowTo create a snippet to repeat the code line in a variable number

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

How to create a numpy array of any shape within an snippet?

For HTML there is a snippet which generates several list entries.
[link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

```
ul>lix3
```

I'm missing the right search term to find the json syntax...may someone can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The [snippet documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) has decent examples that should hopefully be able to help.

Comment: I saw this page and found no suitable solution. The question is how to pass a variable in the prefix.

Comment: @incognito you might need to provide a code sample of what you're after.

Comment: Its rly just like the linked example, wehe create 3 lines of html code... I want to create a dataframe like 'pd.Dataframe([[val1, val2], [val3, val4]])'  by typing sth. like dfx2,2 and fill the vals with tab

Comment: @incognito emmet support like that is baked into VS Code directly and probably doesn't use the standard snippet functionality but as an extension instead.

Comment: hmm, thats lame ;) ... but ty for reply

Comment: @incognito you can always file a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode.